# What is the word for the person who dislikes "Phony" people?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I want to know the word which can describe the personality trait of disliking "Phony" people. Misanthrope is too extreme and generalizes hating human race.

P.S: Any word which can suit personality of Holden from "Catcher in the rye" will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the three best one-word descriptions of Holden Caulfield are "*crazy*" (his own word), *pretentious* (a literary critic's word), and *idealistic* (my word) or *unrealistic* (also my word). Everybody's somewhat of a phony (see Erving Goffman's *[The Presentation of Self in Everyday Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Presentation_of_Self_in_Everyday_Life)*). Nobody likes extreme phonies. That makes "the personality trait of disliking 'Phony' people" a normal trait that deserves no special label.

Comment: I don't have the privileges to vote up/down a post yet.

Comment: That was a tongue-in-cheek reponse, not a nudge, atams!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Pardon me, if this comes out as naive. As English is not my first language, I was not able to understand the context of "not a nudge" part of your response. I know its literal meaning but can you please tell me the meaning you intended.

Comment: Holden was the biggest phoney.

Answer (score 1):

### An upright personality

> **upright**  *adj*
>
> Adhering strictly to moral principles; righteous.

source: thefreedictionary.com

for example:

> Louise: A widow in her late 60's to early 70's, who is in a weak and sickly condition but maintains her pride through her elegant and upright personality.

Answer (score -1):

Someone who recognizes hypocrisy (or phoniness) is likely to be

> cynical

seeing the worst in others.

Comment: Hmm. You don't have to be cynical to dislike 'phoney people'.

Comment: @EleventhDoctor Sure, but the OP's mention of misanthrope and Holden Caulfield make 'cynic' the closest one-word fit. Otherwise it's just 'doesn't like phony people'.